# How to associate Firestore fields with BigQuery columns using Stream Firestore to BigQuery?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

I'm utilizing the Stream Firestore to BigQuery extension. My objective is to link each Firestore document field to a corresponding BigQuery column. Currently, this extension stores the Firestore document as a JSON string in the "data" column of BigQuery. I retrieve data using the JSON_EXTRACT function in BigQuery queries, like so:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.status') AS status,
    COUNT(*) AS status_count
FROM 
    ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}.${appConfig.BIG_QUERY_DATASET_ID}.table_name
```

However, I aim to allocate each field to its own separate column instead.

I've attempted the following query. It creates either a materialized view or a standard view, and it works as expected. However, I'm anticipating the creation of the schema automatically within the table itself, not just within the view, using the Firestore to BigQuery extension.
the query is:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}.${appConfig.BIG_QUERY_DATASET_ID}.view_name` AS
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.dealerZipCode') AS dealerZipCode,
    JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.address') AS address
FROM 
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}.${appConfig.BIG_QUERY_DATASET_ID}.table_name`;
```